# How are cotyledons able to affect the structure of plants?

Tags: plant-anatomy

How are cotyledons able to affect the structure of plants? I am asking in the context of leaf venation, root and stem structures.

Comment: Did you Google this? It's a basic in botany. If you have an intro Biology textbook, it will be there. See what you can find, and if you have a specific question, edit your question to include the information that confuses you. Thanks.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, I did. The question is not only about what are they-- which I can find out but more about how they can affect the structure of plants: this is something I wasn't able to figure out. I have edited the question to make it clearer. I hope this helps. Thank you : )

Comment: This is still *basic plant biology*, one of the first things one learns about plants: are they monocots or dicots? As I said, if you have an intro Biology text, it's there. And it's everywhere on the internet. This is an answer you can find for yourself if you look and read. Getting answers fed to you cuts down on your work but doesn't help you in the long run, which is why we require evidence of an attempt to answer a question on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Cotyledon is a structure of embryos of seed-bearing plants. During seed germination, cotyledon is raised up above the soil and turns green temporarily. They temporarily carry out photosynthesis for net food production for a few days during which the plant's leaves are still underdeveloped, unable to carry out photosynthesis at sufficient rate.

After the leaves become maturely developed and start carrying out photosynthesis, producing food at sufficient rate, cotyledons fall off onto the soil. They are decomposed by putrefying bacteria in soil and converted into nutrients, which dissolve in soil water and can be absorbed into plant.

**Edited to add:** To answer the question "how are cotyledons able to affect the structure of plants?", we have to clear up some ambiguities within the question itself.

Your question is, "How are cotyledons able to affect the structure of plants?". Instead, you may want to ask, "What is the effect of cotyledons on plant structure?" and "how do cotyledons affect plant structure?" The former ask what the effect is, and the latter ask to explain the process of "affecting". These two questions might be what you want to actually ask.

In Biology, when you are relating two concepts to each other, you have to know what they mean. Visually, you are trying to fill out the gap between the two:

$$\text{cotyledons}\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow\text{plant structure}$$

However, the ambiguity lies in each of the two concepts. What attribute of "cotyledons" are you referring to? What "plant structure" are you referring to? By "cotyledons", are you referring to "the development of cotyledons during seed germination"? This was what my previous effort was trying to answer. By "plant structure", do you mean "dry mass"?

Another way to think about it, when you ask "how does $X$ affect $Y$?" very often $X$ is an explanatory variable (or independent variable), while $Y$ is a response variable (or dependent variable). "cotyledons" and "plant structure" are not variables themselves. Variables are attributes which varies. For example, when you simply say "eye" is the variable, it is not clear how it varies because it is simply a body part. However, "eye color" is a variable because it varies - brown, blue and green. To apply the same logic, how does "cotyledon" vary? How does "plant structure" vary?

I really wish to know what your motivation for the question is. If it is a homework, it is implicit and please ask your teacher to clarify. If it is out of curiosity, target what you are truly asking. The question is simply too ambiguous to answer.

Comment: I have edited this. I hope you can understand what I am trying to ask :)

Comment: Do you mean "how does removal of cotyledons affect structure of vascular bundle development"? The most ambiguous part of your question is still "cotyledon". Do you mean the size of it, or simply the presence of it?

Comment: I assume I correctly imply your question. After removal of cotyledons, the young seedlings cannot carry out photosynthesis for food production at sufficient rate for a period of time as the leaves are still underdeveloped. In this period, food is continuously mobilized for growth and development of seedlings without replacement. This leads to net food consumption. With limited availability of food in seedling, it will soon enter food shortage and eventually deplete its food.

Comment: Without enough food (to provide energy and building materials), growth and development is stunted to conserve food for survival. With stunted growth and development of vascular bundles, they appear shorter and thinner than those in seedlings with intact cotyledons.

Comment: I think - perhaps - you're reading too much into this question; it's not sophisticated enough to be probing the depths of energy production/genetic expression/other. i think it's asking the difference between monocots and dicots, but the wording is poor. That's just my opinion. It's great that you're teaching, and trying hard to understand the OP, but we tend not to answer such basic questions, especially when no research effort is shown.

Comment: I just wish I could help. The question is simply too ambiguous to answer. I recall the OP said they are a high school student and usually high school curriculum emphasizes energy usage in seed germination. That's why I chose to answer the question like so.

Comment: "I just wish I could help." That's perfectly understandable, and laudable. I didn't mean to minimize cotyledon's ability to supply energy. Just thinking out loud. Botany was one of my favorite Biology courses, and I have a ginkgo tree because it's a monocotyledonous *tree* (which is cool!), but I couldn't elucidate the precise mechanisms responsible for vascular tissue patterning.